# Add media query rule directly to the SVG path, polygon or rect

Tags: html, css, svg, vector, media-queries

I have this SVG which is being added as an image via `CSS`, but I would like to hide a part of it on smaller screens. It would not be an issue if the `SVG` itself was added directly to the `HTML`, but since I have it only this way, the class does not work.

Is it even possible to add the `media query` directly to the `path, polygon, rect` directly to the SVG itself, or is there some other way to do this?

SVG is been added as a background image to the :before element.

So something like this...

```html
<svg height="210" width="500">
  <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
  <polygon style="@media(max-width: 992px) {display: none}" points="150,10 40,108 190,78 10,78 160,198" style="fill:blue;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:nonzero;"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'is being added as an img via CSS' - is it a background image or an img element (in which case I can't work out where CSS would be involved).

Comment: @AHaworth Yes, sorry - it's been added as a background image to the :before element

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I found a partial solution it seems: it's possible to add a `<style>` tag inside the SVG, and apply the .class style in there...

But it seems to work only when the SVG is the only element on the page, not within the other elements...

```
<svg>
   <style type="text/css">
      @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
          .class {
             display: none;
          }
       }
   </style>
</svg>
```